# Developing a React Native Expo application for Android TV

Tags: react-native, expo, android-tv

I'm trying to develop an application for Android TV using React Native Expo. When launching the app on a virtual emulator, it launches with phone screen size.

Do I have to make changes to the app for it to launch correctly on a Android TV?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to update your app.json:

```
"android": {
      ...
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "MAIN",
          "category": [
            "LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

This will automatically update the AndroidManifest.xml .MainActivity with the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

https://gist.github.com/miazga/2e6449e0c591e3ac8e22185b2edb447d
https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-tv